# Vue and TypeScript: Cannot find name 'exports'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webkit

After changing my `App.vue` to use typescript I now get a compiler error:

> [tsl] ERROR in \src\main.ts(2,23)
>         TS2304: Cannot find name 'exports'.

And if I let vue-serve recompile from a change I get the same error again but also in `App.vue`:

> [tsl] ERROR in src\main.ts(2,23)
>         TS2304: Cannot find name 'exports'.
>
> [tsl] ERROR in src\App.vue.ts(2,23)
>         TS2304: Cannot find name 'exports'.
>
> [tsl] ERROR in src\App.vue.ts(13,1)
>         TS2304: Cannot find name 'exports'.

A simple example typescript vue App created with VueCli3:

**main.ts**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from '@/store'

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  components: { App } //Removed render: h=> h() since it was throwing "any type" TS error. "Exports" error would throw either way.
}).$mount('#app')
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from "vue-class-component";

@Component
export default class App extends Vue {

}

</script>
```

Why is this happening? This is a default vue-cli app, except with the `App.vue` has been changed to use typescript.

All the appropriate webkit bits and pieces exist (I've been struggling with this for 2 weeks now) as this works completely fine with other typescript files (like and component router uses), and vue typescript files, until `App.vue` uses typescript, or any module that `App.vue` imports uses typescript.

Sometimes it compiles just fine, and the error shows up in the console `ReferenceError: exports is not defined` instead. I can't reliably reproduce one or the other, sometimes it throws the compiler error, sometimes it throws the reference error at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in the past.

may be try to import like

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import * as router from './router'
import * as store from '@/store'
```

- as  is the way to import on ES6